# How do I merge a number of documents into one pdf in the pdf printer

Tags: printing

I have installed the pdf printer (CUPS) but have noticed that I am unable to print a number of documents through merging into one document.  How can I do this?  I was able to merge documents in the pdf Creator, while using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

you can use PDF Split and Merge for that. Search for it in the Software Center or open a terminal (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`) and type

```
sudo apt-get install pdfsam
```

After that you can open the GUI version and merge/split PDFs with it. You can also use the terminal like this:

```
pdfsam-console -f input1.pdf -f input2.pdf -o output.pdf concat
```